# WordPress custom fields outside html labels

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom field with Advanced Custom Fields plugin called 'colaboradores' with fields logo (image), direccion (string) and mapa (image);

In **archive-colaboradores.php**, I call the WP_Quer. In short, code is:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'colaboradores',
        'pagination' => false
    ); ?>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'colaboradores' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

So in content-colaboradores.php I show my custom fields with *the_field()*:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<?php $image = get_field( 'logo' ); ?>
<?php echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" >'; ?>

<?php echo '<p>' . the_field('direccion') . '</p>'; ?>

<?php $image = get_field( 'mapa' ); ?>
<?php echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" >'; ?>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Everything is fine except direccion, which is always outside the 



 tag checking with Google Chrome:

[image: address is outside the <p> tags]

I've removed all the code previous to *' . the_field('direccion') . '*

'; ?> but the problem persists.

Do you know why is it hapening? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I`ve found the problem: *the_field()* includes the echo: [ACF - the_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)[/link], final code which works is: `<div class="col-md-6"><?php the_field('direccion'); ?></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant be certain as dev tools doesnt show anything out of the ordinary but maybe try wrapping the_field in some tags to make sure nothing out of the ordinary is coming through.

`<?php echo '<p>' . strip_tags(trim(the_field('direccion'))) . '</p>'; ?>`

I put the strip tags in there because thats normally why chrome and other browsers would put content outside of an inline tag like a p tag

Other than that, maybe try letting wordpress format the paragraph tags, and see if it runs then

`<?php echo apply_filters("the_content",get_field('direccion')); ?>`

See if either of them work?